# S-Parameters and Received Power for Implant Antenna

Tags: electrical-engineering, electromagnetism, telecommunication, biomedical-engineering, rf-electronics

I am simulating an implant antenna using the Ansys HFSS EM simulation tool - the simulation setup looks something like this, with a transmitting (TX) antenna of transmit power $P_{TX}$ and transmit gain $G_{TX}$ transmitting to a receive (RX) implant antenna of gain $G_{RX}$, which receives a power $P_{RX}$. For this test scenario, the TX antenna is excited by a port P1 and port P2 is used to measure the received power P2 at the implant antenna. Both antennas have been impedance matched to their respective ports. For this scenario, $P_{TX}$ = 30 dBm, $G_{TX}$ = 3.4 dBi and $G_{RX} \approx -34 \hspace{1mm}dBi$.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I am trying to calculate the power received by the implanted antenna based on the simulated $s_{21}$ value. Currently I am using this formula:

$$ P_{RX} = \lvert s_{21} \rvert^2 P_{TX} $$

However, when I use this equation, the result is $\approx$ 30 dB larger than expected. I am wondering if this is the correct approach to take to calculate the received power at the antenna based on the simulated s21 value.

Thanks for your help.